# 301 Htaccess Redirect Rule

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301

Need help with an 301 htaccess redirect rule doing the following for all the files in these paths:

www.name.com/wordA/wordB/*      to        www.name.com/new_word/wordA/wordB/*

we are basically adding "new_word" to the new url string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
RewriteRule ^wordA/wordB/.*$ /new_word/$0 [R=301]
```

Comment: Hi Thanks so much. Do I need a RewriteCond above that? If so what should it be? Thanks again.

Comment: No you shouldn't need a RewriteCond from what you've described

Comment: Im going to have three WordA and five WordB for each WordA for a total of 15 paths. Is there a way to combine that in one rule instead of having 15 rewrite rules?

Comment: Figured out how to do it. Thanks again.